# Jsoup debug POST request

Tags: java, http, post, jsoup

```
/** Jre 1.5 */
Map<String, String> paramsMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
/** add few params into paramsMap */

/** Jsoup 1.6.3*/
String post = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .data(paramsMap)
    .method(Method.POST)
    .toString();
```

Variable `post` contains just `org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection@15a62c31`. Method `toString()` for `Connection` is not overloaded.

Is there a way to print and examine POST request that is constructed by jsoup? And no to use packet sniffers.

Comment: Are properties from that method enough for your needs: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#request() ?

Comment: @Tomek it seems i have missed method `Collection<Connection.KeyVal> Connection.Request.data()`. I'll test it.

Comment: @Tomek I have not found in the documentation that it's ensured that params are parsed in same order that they are add to the POST with method data("key","val").

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on logging for HttpURLConnection class. 
Adding

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

param to java utils would solve your logging problem.